# Listing facts with uncertainty

Tags: prolog

I have stated the procedure fact for observable findings, like this:

```
fact(fever)
fact(flu)
```

So, in SICStus, after asserting the facts, I do the listing of the facts and I get this:

```
| ?- listing(fact).      
fact(fever).
fact(flu).

yes
```

| ?-

But now I want to add uncertainty to the facts, like this, as an example:

```
fact(fever) :: likely
fact(flu) :: certain
```

My question is, how to do listing of the facts considering the newly added operator "::" and the uncertainty? I've tried many different ways, like

```
listing(fact(X) :: Y).
```

but it keeps giving me errors like this:

```
! Type error in argument 1 of listing/1
! expected list of pred_spec_tree, but found fact(_4643)::_4639
! goal:  listing(user:(fact(_4643)::_4639))
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use a tuple predicate like `fact/2`?

Then you specify:

```
fact(fever,likely).
fact(flu,certain).
```

By using `listing(fact).`, you can list all facts.

Or you can use the `findall` operator:

```
findall(::(X,Y),::(fact(X),Y),L).
```

If you want to use the `::` operator between two arguments, you need to register it:

```
op(900, xfx, user:(::)).
```

Where `900` is the priority (how tight does it bind compared to other operators, `xfx` the mode and `user:(::)` the operator of course. But this is actually more syntactical sugar: in Prolog an expression like `foo::bar` actually means a predicate `::/2` applied to `foo` and `bar` thus: `::(foo,bar)`.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! i'll stick with the findall operator ;)